# Latex poster (baposter package): footnote

Tags: miktex, baposter

Using the baposter package in Latex to create a poster, I have issue to create a footnote. I created a headerbox, but as you can see on the figure below, space between the first and second line is bigger than between other lines. Why? How to change it to have equal spacing? Additionally, there is space after the last line (between the text and the bottom border of the box) that I would also like to remove.

[image: Poster]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% baposter Landscape Poster 
% LaTeX Template 
% Version 1.0 (11/06/13) 
% 
% baposter Class Created by: 
% Brian Amberg (baposter@brian-amberg.de) 
% 
% This template has been downloaded from: 
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com 
% 
% License: 
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/) 
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images 
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math 
\usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables 
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing 
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures


\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns 
\usepackage{vwcol} 
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns 
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate} 
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt} \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} \setlength{\parsep}{0pt} }

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{ 
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes 
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing 
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster 
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster 
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color 
headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side) 
headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side) 
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes 
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes 
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded 
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left 
headerheight=0.2\textheight, % Height of the header 
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded 
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes %textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation 
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes 
} %---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% TITLE SECTION  
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
{\includegraphics[width=6em]{logo.png}} % First university/lab logo on the left 
{\bf\textsc{Poster}\vspace{0.3em}} % Poster title 
{\textsc{\normalsize{Name }}\\ \vspace{0.2em} \normalsize{University} } % Author names and institution 
{\includegraphics[width=6em]{logo.png}} % Second university/lab logo on the right

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- % OBJECTIVES %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
\headerbox{}{name=foottext, column=0, span=4, above=bottom, headerborder=none, boxheaderheight=1pt, headershape=rectangle}{ \begin{vwcol}[widths={0.8,0.2}] \tiny{Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariature nim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur} \newpage \footnotesize{aa} \end{vwcol} }

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be due `vwcol`. As you don't want text flowing from left column to right column, I think it's better that you use a `tabular` with `paragraph` columns:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% baposter Landscape Poster 
% LaTeX Template 
% Version 1.0 (11/06/13) 
% 
% baposter Class Created by: 
% Brian Amberg (baposter@brian-amberg.de) 
% 
% This template has been downloaded from: 
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com 
% 
% License: 
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/) 
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images 
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math 
\usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables 
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing 
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures


\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns 
\usepackage{vwcol} 
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns 
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate} 
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt} \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} \setlength{\parsep}{0pt} }

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{ 
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes 
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing 
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster 
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster 
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color 
headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side) 
headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side) 
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes 
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes 
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded 
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left 
headerheight=0.2\textheight, % Height of the header 
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded 
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes %textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation 
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes 
} 
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% TITLE SECTION  
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
{\includegraphics[width=6em]{logo.png}} % First university/lab logo on the left 
{\bf\textsc{Poster}\vspace{0.3em}} % Poster title 
{\textsc{\normalsize{Name }}\\ \vspace{0.2em} \normalsize{University} } % Author names and institution 
{\includegraphics[width=6em]{logo.png}} % Second university/lab logo on the right

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% OBJECTIVES 
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
\headerbox{}{name=foottext, column=0, span=4, above=bottom, headerborder=none, boxheaderheight=1pt, headershape=rectangle}{\begin{tabular}{p{.75\linewidth}|p{.2\linewidth}}
\tiny{Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. 
Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos 
qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, 
adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. 
Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi 
consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, 
vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariature nim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam 
corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea 
voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur}
& \footnotesize{aaa}
\end{tabular}}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image]